# How do I format my results with DecimalFormat if I'm using a separate class?

Tags: java, driver, program-entry-point, decimalformat

So I'm very new to Java, and I'm currently trying to create a driver class that will use my Mortgage class to calculate a mortgage. I have everything working except that my output does not format the results to two decimal places (0.00), even though I have the code there. Here is a piece of my driver code:

```
Mortgage mortgage1 = new Mortgage(annualInterestRate, numOfYears, loanAmount);

  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Monthly Payment is: " 
  + mortgage1.monthlyPayment() + "\n" + "Your Total Payment is: " + 
  mortgage1.totalPayment());
```

It works perfectly fine, and outputs the correct numbers, but doesn't format them correctly. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Well you're not actually *using* `df` at all. You need to pass the result of calling `monthlyPayment()` and `totalPayment()` to the `format` method. For example:

```
Mortgage mortgage1 = new Mortgage(annualInterestRate, numOfYears, loanAmount);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
    "Your Monthly Payment is: " 
    + df.format(mortgage1.monthlyPayment()) + "\n"
    + "Your Total Payment is: "
    + df.format(mortgage1.totalPayment()));
```

Comment: Ah I see, I was unclear on how the DecimalFormat class actually works, and how to express it in Java. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating DecimalFormat object but not using it.

Here is a sample usage:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
String result = df.format(123456); 
System.out.println(result);
```